# Heikin Ashi without a stock's entire history?

Tags: python, finance, stock, trading, technical-indicator

I'm trying to loop through hundreds of stock tickers, calculating the most recent Heikin-Ashi open and close value for each. However, you need the previous HA open and close to calculate the current HA open. Is there any way to do this without having to deal with a stock's entire history?

Answer (score 1):

You do not need the entire history but the more data you have the least will be the effect on the most recent values.

For the calculation of the first HA open, you need to use the normal open. After that, you can iteratively calculate the remaining HA opens.